# Callback function and parameters

Tags: javascript

so I was learning about callback functions, and I was wondering why you can't use parameters in the callback. I explain myself with this code:

```
function one (name) {
  console.log(`Hey ${name}`);
}
function two (fn){
  console.log('Let me salute you:');
  fn();
}

two(one);
```

If I try to put `two(one('Chris'))`, won't work, It will give you an error and call the `one` function first. So, how it should be done?
thanks in advance!

Comment: `one` is a function *reference*, `one('Chris')` is a function *call*.

Comment: `two` needs to take both a function reference and any parameter to pass to it as parameters.

Comment: *"So, how it should be done?"* - If you want to add a parameter then you can wrap the function call in a new function.  For example:  `two(function () { one('Chris'); });`  So the `fn` parameter in the `two` function is that outer unnamed (anonymous) function.